# How can a mail server implement POP3/APOP without the user's passwords in clear-text?

Tags: pop3, password-hash

Quoth [RFC 1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939), the standard that defines basic POP3 without extensions.

```
         Examples:
             S: +OK POP3 server ready <1896.697170952@dbc.mtview.ca.us>
             C: APOP mrose c4c9334bac560ecc979e58001b3e22fb
             S: +OK maildrop has 1 message (369 octets)

             In this example, the shared  secret  is  the  string  `tan-
             staaf'.  Hence, the MD5 algorithm is applied to the string

                <1896.697170952@dbc.mtview.ca.us>tanstaaf

             which produces a digest value of

                c4c9334bac560ecc979e58001b3e22fb
```

If I imagine myself as the mail server at the point when the APOP command arrives, I've got the following items:

- The challenge string which I randomly generated a moment ago.
- The claimed user-name and MD5 hash from the client which may or may not be valid.
- The user's password protected by bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2, or a similar hashing method.

You'll notice that the user's password in clear-text is not on the list, because we're not meant to do that in this day and age.

I still occasionally see the APOP challenge in the greeting when connecting to POP3 services. Are these services storing their user's passwords in the clear? If not, how are they implementing APOP without them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no plaintext exchange of the user's password in this example. The password is hashed (not encrypted) on the client side, then the hash is sent to the server.  The server performs the same hash of the password it has previously stored in the specified user's account, and if the two hashes match then access is granted.  At no point is the client made aware of the hash that the server calculates.

Hashes can't be reversed, so there is no way for a MITM attacker to recover the original password from intercepting the submitted hash (the attacker could brute force its own password until a matching hash is submitted, but that takes a long time, and servers tend to implement countermeasures against that kind of thing).

Whether or not the user's password is stored in plaintext or not *on the server side* is irrelevant to APOP.  That is an implementation detail of the server's account storage.  One would *hope* that the server is encrypting the password in storage.  But the server is required to have access to the actual password nonetheless.